# SFSpeechRecognizer 216 Error with Multiple Requests

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioengine, sfspeechrecognizer

I have an implementation of AVAudio and SFSpeechRecognizer that generally works fine the first few times.  However, after one or more requests, I am getting a 216 Error.

Despite numerous questions about what these errors, 216, 203 and others, might mean on SO and other sites, no one seems sure.  Some [suggest the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44767316/ios-speech-recognition-error-domain-kafassistanterrordomain-code-216-null) is that you need to include a line

```
request.endAudio() // Added line to mark end of recording
```

Others say, you can only do this from within the completion block or else you will [get a 203 error](http://%20%22endAudio%22%20not%20allow%20to%20call%20from%20outside%20the%20recognitionTaskWithRequest%20block,):

Another person in [an Apple Developer forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/51938) suggested that the 216 error is actually a Nuance Error because, they say, Nuance handles some of the backend processing for Apple.  Nuance's SDK for IOS actually [does have an error 216](https://developer.nuance.com/public/Help/DragonMobileSDKReference_iOS/Error-codes.html):

```
Invalid action-setup data were detected. The action cannot be executed. Contact Nuance Support.
```

I have added the `request.endAudio()` but I can't seem to eliminate this error that generally pops up by the third or fourth recognition task.

Can anyone suggest a definite solution to this or shed additional light on what it does.  It would be awesome if an Apple engineer were to answer definitively.

Thanks for any suggestions or insights.

Comment: You did quite a good research through all these SO topics.
I have a similar problem
The next solved:
`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:&error];`

Comment: @user6631314 how did you solve this problem? Would you mind sharing your solution? Thanks!